# Which song is playing on the radio in Wild (2014)?

Tags: soundtrack, wild

During the first 15 minutes of the 2014 movie Wild, Cheryl sets off from her motel and takes lift in a man's truck whose son is sitting in the front seat with him. In that scene the man turns on the radio and a song starts playing. That song reminds Cheryl of her mother. Probably they used to dance on that song when she was a kid. Suddenly that man's son turns off the radio and Cheryl's flashback is ended. I would like to know the name of that song.

Comment: Does it appear in one of the soundtracks: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2305051/soundtrack?ref_=tt_trv_snd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually take some of the text I hear and put in in google with the term "Lyrics".

The song you're referring to is "I Can Never Go Home Anymore" from "The Shangri-Las"

You can find it on YouTube, [here](https://youtu.be/dYdr-MslXkw).

Or you can search on YouTube for [some more versions](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=+I+Can+Never+Go+Home+Anymore) of it.

(and yes, it's also on the soundtrack-list I see now)

Comment: Thanks. When I watched the movie, I could not really hear the lyrics properly & when I was surfing through the soundtrack-list, it did not appear in first 7-8 songs, so got frustrated and sought help here :-)